# Why PhpStorm doesn't know PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm trying to configure `PhpStorm 2017.2` to use `PhpUnit 5` for my `PHP 5.6` project.

1. I've downloaded the `phpunit-5.7.21.phar` file from [the official source](https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-5.7.phar) and placed it in my PHP 5.6 installation dir.
2. In *PhpStorm Settings >> Languages & Frameworks >> PHP >> Test Frameworks*, I've linked to the `.phar` executable and set the default config file to a `phpunit.xml` in the project root directory

[image]

3. Here are the contents of `phpunit.xml`:

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

I'm trying to structure tests in a `tests/unit` directory within which my source file project structure would be mirrored as described [in the manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html). For instance:

```
// project files:
ClassOne.php
vendor/
  ClassTwo.php
  Utility.php

// test files
tests/unit/
  ClassOneTest.php
  vendor/
    ClassTwoTest.php
    UtilityTest.php
```

I have two problems though:

**First**, I don't know how to configure PhpStorm to create tests within `tests/unit/` mirroring the sructure with respect to the project root. When I create a test, by default the file is put in the same directory as the project file.

**Secondly**, I don't know how to get PhpStorm to index the PHPUnit source code. Even though I've linked to `phpunit-5.7.21.phar` file as shown above, the IDE complains when I create a test:

```
namespace vendor;
class UtilityTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{}
```

> Undefined class PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

#### Update 1

I solved the 2nd problem by adding the directory where I had saved the `.phar` to the PhpStorm include path, set in *Settings >> Languages & Frameworks >> PHP >> Include Path tab*. Alternatively, I could just put the `.phar` file within the project directory and it will be indexed.

I still need help with my first problem.

#### Update 2

Thanks to Ástþór's answer I figured out how to get PhpStorm to mirror the project structure within a dedicated tests directory. Go to *PhpStorm Settings >> Directories* and select the base testing directory. The click `Test` near the top to mark it as a Test Sources Root

[image]

The next time you create a test, it will automatically be placed in that directory.

Comment: If you downvote, please leave feedback as to why so I can learn what makes this a poor question in your opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark a directory with your source classes as "Source root" and a directory with tests as "Test Sources Root". After that directories will be pre-filled on a test creation (e.g. via ctrl+shift+T on a source class).
Not sure though if that would work fine with your "mirroring" system: I guess you would still have to manually adjust directories for the part of your tests

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking up how to declare a folder as a "*Test Sources Root*" in PhpStorm.  When I right-click the `tests/` directory the options I see under "*Mark Directory As*" are Resource Root, Excluded and Sources Root.